# Add a button in checkout to empty cart and redirect to shop page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I would like to have a cancel order button behind/under the checkout button in Woocommerce. Then after a customer click this button, the shopping cart would be empty, redirect to shop page.

I tried several things in the template with the woocommerce_cancelled_order
in template `form-checkout.php`.

But I cannot figure this out. How can I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In checkout the **order object** doesn't exist until customer clicks on "Place Order", so you can't use the hook [`woocommerce_cancelled_order`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Form_Handler.html#723) located in `cancel_order()` method.

In checkout page you need to empty cart instead using a custom button and the following code will empty the cart and redirect to shop when "Cancel order" is clicked:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_submit', 'checkout_reset_button', 10 );
function checkout_reset_button(){
    echo '<br><br>
    <a class="button alt" style="text-align:center;" href="?cancel=1">'.__("Cancel order", "woocommerce").'</a>';
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'checkout_reset_cart' );
function checkout_reset_cart() {
    if( ! is_admin() && isset($_GET['cancel']) ) {
        WC()->cart->empty_cart();
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec! Your solution is perfect.